# Angular Material sidenav mini variant with submenus

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, material-design, angular-material

I use the Angular 5 and Material design.
I have an angular material [navigation drawer mini variant](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-behavior) as the side navigation menu for my application ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWGa4.jpg))
With the arrow in the top we hide the items, leaving only the icons.

What I want to do is to add submenus for some of the menu items.

When the menu is collapsed we would have a popover appearing with the links to the submenus:
[menu popover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmkXP.jpg)

When the menu is expanded we would have an arrow to expand the submenu under the menu:
 [menu expanded with children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ8td.jpg)

I found several solutions but none doing exactly this. Here some links:
[Angular Material Tree](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview)

[Dynamic nested menu using Angular Material](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-menus)

[Bootstrap popover](https://mdbootstrap.com/angular/advanced/popover/#api), but I would prefer to find something similar in Angular Material.

[And this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43174068/how-do-you-create-a-nested-collapsing-menu-with-angular-material2)

Does someone have some idea of how to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Begoña

Comment: Show us what you did try till now... any code? Your question is just a kind of concept without code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer could be a comment, but for reasons of text-size limit and visibility, I'm writing it here.

The bad news is that right now, there isn't an official way to do it natively provided by Material.

But the good news is that I've found a nice **workaround**. I explain you how I'm managing it **below**:

---

1. Implement [this material standard menu](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples)(see the last example in the bottom of the page on stackblitz) in your app**, take example by [this live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4gmby?file=styles.scss) to manage an `isExpanded` value with its relative icon/text exclusion
2. Then use [ngClass](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ngclass-ngstyle/) directive to add a custom class conditionally on the `isExpanded` value that will set the `width` to `N px !important`, where "N" is a custom value.

   `!important` is needed to override default values.
3. Now, the most difficult part is the pop-over. You could use [this library](https://mdbootstrap.com/angular/advanced/popover/) popovers, or maybe [this library's one](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples). Css customization to override positioning and colour values is a must.

   To edit and override the library tags and class properties, use the `::ng-deep` prefix (E.G:: `::ng-deep ngb-popover-window { /* customization here */ }`).

   The only way to make it going over the material sidenav is with a css override, but it's quite a minefield and the risk is to mess up the current app layout.

   A good alternative to pop-over (and it's also more easy-implementable one) could be to change menu width when mouse is over to show a second column which will contain the sub-section links...

   I've seen something similar [here](https://github.com/Ravi-Rajpurohit/mini-md-sidenav), but it's just to get ideas.
4. For the menu content, consider duplicating your code with different
   behaviours depending on `isExpanded` value, so you can "easily"
   manage a treeview and a pop-over submenu view.

SOURCE: I'm doing this right now

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but got a nicer workaround for the solution which is less intrusive https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-rail-drawer. All you do is include the module and then set mode as rail (this is the name for the icon only menu in material.io)

**Demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-mini-variant